# The view music.views.favorite didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, http

[image]

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
> response = get_response(request)
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django-1.10.6-py3.4.egg\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 198, in _get_response
> "returned None instead." % (callback.__module__, view_name)
> ValueError: The view music.views.favorite didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
> [11/Mar/2017 15:34:57] "POST /music/1/favorite/ HTTP/1.1" 500 56886
> ```

Comment: Share your `views.py` and please take advantage of the code formatting option in your question.

Answer (score 1):

That's because in your `else` clause you are not returning anything! You're just saving the `selected_song`. You should return a HttpResponse object (i.e usually with `render` or `HttpResponseRedirect`)